# Finding a unique character

Tags: c, find, character, words

My task is to compare some words and to find a character which is not used in both of them. Here is my code. But I'm getting a warning:

```
[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'ret' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default].
```

And when I'm trying to run it it says `consolepauser.exe stopped working`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char ret(char a[1][10],char b[3][10])
{
        int i,j,p,t;
        for (i=0;i<1;i++)
            for (j=0;j<10;j++)
                for (p=0;p<3;p++)
                    for (t=0;t<10;t++)
                    {
                        if (tolower(a[i][j]==tolower(b[p][t])))
                        {
                            p=3;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (p==2)
                            if (t==9) return tolower(a[i][j]) ;
                    }
        return 'N';

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char k[3][10]={"cHaOs","TOP","blAa"};
    char b[1][10]={"SomeThIng"};
    char q[1][10]={"HaPa"};
    if (ret(b[1][10],k[3][10])='N') printf("No character") ;
    else printf("%c",ret(b[1][10],k[3][10])) ;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: `if (ret(b[1][10],k[3][10])='N')` you should use `==` to compare for equality.

Comment: @timrau thnx but now I'm experiencing different problems. Check the description

Comment: In the call, `b[1][10]` is indexing out of bounds of the `b` array, and is trying to pass a single character to `ret`.  You need just `b` in the first argument.  Similarly with `k` and `k[3][10]`.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the parameters as:

```
if (ret(b, k) == 'N') printf("No character");
else printf("%c", ret(b, k));
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'ret' makes pointer from integer without a cast

`b[1][10]` is a `char`, not a variable of type `char [1][10]`, you should call `ret()` like this: `ret(b, k)`. Others are similar.

Note: the valid indexes of `char b[1][10];` are `b[0][0]`, `b[0][1]`, ..., `b[0][9]`, the indexes in `b[1][10]1 are out-of-bounds, and will cause undefined behavior.

Here is a syntax fixed version of your code, you may want to compare it with your original code to find out other problems in it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char ret(char a[1][10],char b[3][10])
{
        int i,j,p,t,e,r;
        for (i=0;i<1;i++)
            for (j=0;j<10;j++)
                for (p=0;p<3;p++)
                    for (t=0;t<10;t++)
                    {
                        if (tolower(a[i][j])==tolower(b[p][t]))
                        {
                            p=3;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (p==2)
                            if (t==9) return tolower(a[i][j]) ;
                    }
        return 'N';

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i,j,p,t,e,r;
    char a,h;
    char k[3][10]={"cHaOs","TOP","blAa"};
    char b[1][10]={"SomeThIng"};
    char q[1][10]={"HaPa"};
    if (ret(b,k)=='N') printf("No character");
    else printf("%c",ret(b,k));

return 0;

}
```